# grammar: why do we or omit the "do"

Tags: grammar

very often we see the description like this:

Many people realize that they didn't do any wrongdoings, so they cannot understand why they have to be punished. or ...., so they cannot understand why do they have to be punished.

or we ask "why do you fight?" can we omit the "do",  say "why you fight?"

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to ELU, McGushin. Questions like this are generally considered too basic for this site, but are in many cases accepted  on the [ell.se] site. You may click on 'flag' above and ask that the moderators migrate your question there.

Answer (score 4):

No, you may not omit the *do*.

A question headed by a *Wh-* interrogative (*who, whom, whose, what, which, where, when, why, how*, and a few others) **must** have a finite verb in the second position<sup>†</sup>; and that verb **must** be either a form of *be* or an *auxiliary* verb.

```
indicative:       interrogative:   
He is right.      Why is he right?    ... the finite verb IS is a form of BE  
You must fight.   Why must you fight? ... the finite verb MUST is a modal auxiliary
```

But if the finite verb in the clause is not one of these, then it must be replaced with a *do* construction (this is called 'DO-support').

```
indicative:       interrogative:   
You fight.       *Why fight you?      ... wrong: FIGHT is not an auxiliary
                 *Why you fight?      ... wrong: there is no verb in second place
                  Why do you fight?   ... right: DO is an auxiliary in second place.
```

A tricky piece  is that *do* and *have* (and a few other verbs) may act as either an auxiliary or as an ordinary *lexical* verb. You must be careful to employ *do* in the second case:

```
indicative:       interrogative:   
They do wrong.   *Why do they wrong?      ... wrong: DO here is not an auxiliary
                  Why do they do wrong?   ... right: the first DO is an auxiliary
He has a car.    *Where has he a car?     ... wrong: HAS here is not an auxiliary (but
                                                 this was at one time acceptable)
                  Where does he have a car? . right: DO-support provides the auxiliary
```

---

<sup>†</sup> *Second* must sometimes be loosely interpreted with *which*, *what* and *whose*; if used as adjectives these are followed by the NP they modify, as in *What courses are you taking?*
* before an utterance indicates that it is not ordinarily acceptable

Comment: I remember reading an article quite recently with the title, "Why dogs eat grass?" I guess the best of us make mistakes too.